# beamer: Place hyperref buttons at very bottom of each page

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I would like to have a set of navigation buttons at the very bottom of every slide, where the buttons lead to different slides depending on the section you are in, for example

```
\hyperlink{startpage}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to start}} 
\hyperlink{thissectionstart}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to section start}} 
\hyperlink{somewhere}{\beamergotobutton{More details}}
\hyperlink{section3}{\beamerskipbutton{Next section}} 
\hyperlink{contactinfo}{\beamerskipbutton{Contact information}}
```

This gives a nice set of buttons, but I would like to have them at the very bottom of each page, without altering the positions of the rest of the text. I tried inserting an

```
\vfill
```

before that, which creates some space between the content and the buttons, but does not push them to the very bottom of the slides.

As I mentioned, the specific links in the buttons will vary on each slide, so I can not use some solutions with a fixed custom footer

Comment: You can create you own footer using the everypage package, but it isn't trivial.  Also, beamer tends to be incompatible with other packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Possibility 1:**

Use Beamers build in navigation

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}[default]
```

[image]

**Possibility 2:**

Put your buttons in the footline

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \quad\hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to start}}%
    \quad\hyperlinksectionstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to section start}}%
    \quad\hyperlink{moredetails}{\beamergotobutton{More details}}%
    \quad\hyperlinksectionstartnext{\beamerskipbutton{Next section}}%
    \quad\hyperlinkpresentationend{\beamerskipbutton{Contact information}}%
    \vspace*{0.2cm}%
}

\begin{document}

    \section{sec1}
    \frame{1}
    \frame{2}

    \begin{frame}[label=moredetails]
        more details
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}
    \frame{3}
    \frame{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am now using option 2. Is there a way to see all available options for `\hyperlink...` somehow? Is there fore example one that leads to the next subsection rather than the next section?

Comment: @user3825755 all available options can be found in http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty So if you want to go to the next subsection use `\hyperlinksubsectionstartnext`

Comment: Very useful link! All my questions are answered I guess

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for your **Possibility 2**. I am trying to declare a `Prevuous section` navigation symbol following the same logic as the already declared `Next section` symbol. I have tried `\quad\hyperlinksectionstartprev{\beamerreturnbutton{previous section}}` and `\quad\hyperlinksectionstartprev{\beamerskipbutton{previous section}}` but it does not jump to the previous section. Is there a way to achieve this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @DavidC. Can you please ask a new question including a MWE?

Answer (score 0):

There are beamer themes that already have such buttons on the bottom. One of them is "Warsaw", the theme of the usual beamer template. Maybe you can find in the sources of "Warsaw" how to modify it to your needs. If that doesn't work for you, you may have some other issue with beamer versions or your pdf-viewer.