# Beamer next slide button

Tags: beamer

I want to add a beamer button which will link to the next page. There is one navigation symbol that does exactly what I want, but I could not find any option to have the same functionality for button.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
page 1
\beamerskipbutton{next page}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
page 2
\beamerskipbutton{next page}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
page 3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The navigation symbol I was referring to is highlighted

[image]

Comment: See here some more options you have for the hyperlinks and buttons usage: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237321/beamer-place-hyperref-buttons-at-very-bottom-of-each-page. Look inside \setbeamertemplate{footline} in possibility 2 and ignore that command... Just adding the comment for other users because I did not found in first google page the result I expected to find (@samcarter's answer does what you want but here are just some more info about hyperlinks and beamer buttons)

Comment: @koleygr Not completely understood your comment(s). Anyway, I was aware of the question you linked. You may notice none of `\hyperlinkpresentationstart`,  `\hyperlinksectionstart`, `\hyperlinksectionstartnext` `\hyperlinkpresentationend` solves my problem.

Comment: the \hyperlink that is the only you did not mentioned solves it. The others is just other options you may need for other reasons. Also you can see there thay there are \beamergotobutton and \beametreturnbutton choises (except of \beamerbutton and \beamerskipbutton). I thought they might help people with similar searches as yours. It is not an answer. Just (in my opinion) a useful linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\hyperlinkslidenext{\beamerbutton{next}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```